# Hide Other DIvs other than the One i have clicked ... In JQuery

Tags: jquery

HI,

i am having html like

```
 <div class="float_left myFormsContainer" id="fm_myforms_container">

     <div id='form1'>
           <p>
             <a id="form43" data-attr="Formentries" href="#">  Personal Form </a>
           </p>
      EDITTED     <div></div>
      </div>
  <div id='form2'>

       <p>
             <a id="form44" data-attr="Formentries" href="#">  Contact Form </a>
         </p>
 </div>

 <div id='form3'>
             <p>
             <a id="form45" data-attr="Formentries" href="#">  Employee Form </a>
         </p>
</div>

</div>
```

In JQuery i have coded like on clicking any a tag

```
    $("#fm_myforms_container a").live("click", function(){


        $("#fm_myforms_container div").hide();//to hide all other divs other than the one what i have clicked...

return false;
      });
```

i am trying to hide all other divs other than the one what i have clicked...

how to do ?? please suggest me.. I am new to JQuery ...

Answer (score 1):

You could use:

```
$("#fm_myforms_container div").not($(this).closest("div")).hide();
```

or if you only want hide the top-level divs:

```
$("#fm_myforms_container > div").not($(this).closest("div")).hide();
```

Comment: I am having some DIvs inside the Div i am clicking , But if i used the code what u have given , its hiding those DIvs too... suggest me...